# Parameters Randomly Being Transferred

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access, parameter-passing

I have an Access Database that is reading data from a SharePoint list,
then outputting the data into an excel spreadsheet There are many queries involved, about 40 total.

Here is the format of each query:

```
    Set qdf20 = db.QueryDefs("<Query Name Here>")
    qdf20!Param1 = Param
    Set rst20 = qdf20.OpenRecordset()           
    qdf20.Close
    rst20.Close
    Set qdf20 = Nothing
    Set rst20 = Nothing
```

This is in a 'For' loop, and the 'Param' changes with each iteration of the loop.
The problem: Some queries work, and some do not. The only thing that is changed
is the query name, the record set name and the query def name. The errors are
totally random. The parameters are in an array, and the for the queries that work,
all the parameters are successfully transferred.

Solutions I have tried are using the Parameters Collection Object, and using the SQL commands directly in VBA, but that didn't help. The error I receive is: "Too few parameters, expected 1". I have read the other posts concerning this same error, but they do not solve the problem.

I'm at my wits-end trying to find a solution. Can anyone offer any insight?
It would be very helpful and much appreciated.

Comment: Try adding `Debug.Print qdef20.SQL` after line 2 and see if the sql makes sense.
You will see the sql in the _immediate_ widow (cntrl+g if it's not open)

Comment: Isolate just one test case and solve the problem with it before moving on to the next. If the errors seem random to you then maybe there are multiple problems. What you have provided here is not a minimal reproducible example. There is no problem with code you have shared.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: When the error "Too few parameters, expected 1" occurs, it prevents the display of all query results. No 'Debug.Print' results are seen in the immediate window when this happens. I can manually run the queries in Access and get the desired results, but the breakdown occurs when using VBA.